# iphone : get coordinates from subviews with respect to self.view

Tags: iphone, coordinates, cgrect

[image: Reference]

Here, A, B ... Z are custom cell with table,

How can I get a `CGRect` with respect to button for the `self.view`? I tried with `CGRectIntersection` and `CGRectUnion` methods but it won't work!
For e.g. I need `CGRect` that give me position of that button in `self.view`

Answer (score 0):

You need two steps of calculation

1. Calculate origin of the cell with respect to the **self.view**
2. Calculate origin of button with respect to the cell

For step 1, you can use

```
[UITableView rectForRowAtIndexPath]
```

e.g. `CGRect rect_cell = [table_view rectForRowAtIndexPath:index_path_target_cell];`

Then for step 2, (if you don't already know button's offset from cell's origin)

```
CGRect rect_button = _button.frame;
CGPoint point_answer = CGPointMake(rect_cell.origin.x + rect_button.origin.x , rect_cell.origin.y + rect_button.origin.y);
```

Comment: from this, how would I get that position within `self.view`?

Comment: To clarify things, the first step is for you to get relative position of the cell from the view, the second step is to add relative position of the button to that. That way, their summation should give you the relative position of the button from the view. What part is problematic for you?

Comment: I forget to add in my question, I do have navigation bar and tabbar as well, which creates the problem? The problem is it gives me some up frame from button.

Comment: Can you print out your table's frame. It should definitely give you different points for different cells at a given time (just checked it - note that it doesn't vary according to scroll, to factor in change due to scroll, you should use contentOffset property of the table)